# jquery select box bug in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using jquery 1.2.6 (can't upgrade because it part of a system).
I'm getting a weird error.

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="state" name="state">
            <option selected="selected"></option>
                        <option value="none">N/A</option>
                        <option value="AK">AK</option>
                        <option value="AL">AL</option>
                        <option value="AR">AR</option>
                        <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                        <option value="CA">CA</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var test = $('#state').val();
    });
</script>
```

when I test in IE9 I'm getting this error when loading the page:

```
"Unable to get value of the property 'specified': object is null or undefined"
```

Why is that?

Comment: Does it work with `document.getElementById('state').value` ?

Comment: @dystroy yes, it does... I guess for now that's a good workaround

Comment: Can you just check if you have the same problem with the last version of jQuery ? It would help find where exactly is the bug (IE, old jQuery, any jQuery).

Comment: @dystroy with the latest jquery there is no error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The value in an option is optional](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/option) (*"If there isn't, the value of an option element is the textContent of the element."*). So you seem to encounter a bug here.

I had a look at [the old jQuery source code](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js) and I found the bug :

```
value = jQuery.browser.msie && !option.attributes.value.specified ? option.text : option.value;
```

`option.attributes.value` is undefined so `option.attributes.value.specified` crashes.

As the bug is in jQuery (more precisely in what looks like an attempt to work around an old IE bug now fixed), it would be legitimate to not use jQuery on this particular task.

Instead of changing the HTML (your HTML is fine), I recommend to use, as a workaround, the vanilla JS solution :

```
var test = document.getElementById('state').value;
```

Note that when I say that the bug is in jQuery, it mainly means the 2008 version of jQuery fails in recent versions of IE while trying to work around bugs of 2008 browsers. You should really tell your architect that keeping this old jQuery isn't a sound decision.

Answer (score 2):

Your selected option does not have a value set, so that is why it is complaining :)

Comment: you're right... I didn't notice that I forgot to add an empty value to the selected option. When I added, the error disappeared

Comment: Well yes, but as per your quote, it falls back to the content of the element and neither is provided here. It could be fixed by either providing a value attribute or some text in the option.

Comment: An empty string isn't null. There still would be no reason for "object is null or undefined". It can be noted that there is no problem on Chrome.